# VBscript adding date to name of zip file

Tags: date, vbscript, zip

I currently have a script that deletes old log files and then takes any files newer than the specified time frame and zips them up into a zip with the name of the localhost.zip.

What I am trying to do is just add the Date when the files were zipped appended onto the name of the zip.

So something ike localhost_Date.zip.

I know that I need to add something after "%computername%" but I am just not sure of the syntax to deal with it.

Thanks for any help in advance. Also if you see any improvements that could be made to my script just let me know. It's pretty much just a beginners workings with tweaking other scripts found online to suit my needs.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFSO, oFolder, sDirectoryPath 
Dim oFileCollection, oFile, sDir 
Dim iDaysOld 

' Specify Directory Path From Where You want to clear the old files 

sDirectoryPath = "C:\Testscripts\testfolder\"

' Specify Number of Days Old File to Delete

iDaysOld = 7

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath) 
Set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files 

For each oFile in oFileCollection

    'Specify the Extension of file that you want to delete 
    'and the number with Number of character in the file extension 



    If LCase(Right(Cstr(oFile.Name), 3)) = "log" Then

        If oFile.DateLastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then 
        oFile.Delete(True) 
        End If 

    End If   
Next 



Set oFSO = Nothing 
Set oFolder = Nothing 
Set oFileCollection = Nothing 
Set oFile = Nothing 



WScript.Echo "Press to start zipping log files."

Dim objFile, objPath, objFolder, Command, PathLogs, RetVal
Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

PathLogs = "C:\Testscripts\testfolder\" 'This path just has some test logs

' Loop through the logs and zip and move each file (if required, you could just move files with an '.log' extension)


Set objPath = objFSO.GetFolder(PathLogs)
For Each objFile In objPath.Files




    If (LCase(objfso.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "log") Then

        ' zip files

        Command = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" a " & PathLogs & "%computername%" & ".zip " & PathLogs & objFile.Name 

        RetVal = objShell.Run(Command,0,true)

    End If

Next

WScript.Echo "Zip Successful."

WScript.Echo "Now Moving Zipped Files into Archived Folder"

'move files

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
objFSO.MoveFile "C:\Testscripts\testfolder\*.zip" , "C:\Testscripts\testfolder\Archived"

WScript.Echo "Move Successful."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skipped the gory details, sorry. Here is a two-line VBScript code to format current date as `yyyy-mm-dd` (keeping in mind that `/` is not allowed in filenames):

```
Dim d : d = Date()
Dim dateStr : dateStr = Year(d) & "-" & Right("00" & Month(d), 2) & "-" & Right("00" & Day(d), 2)

' Usage
Command = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" a " & PathLogs & "%computername%" & "-" & dateStr & ".zip " & PathLogs & objFile.Name
```

Apart from that, this line:

```
If LCase(Right(Cstr(oFile.Name), 3)) = "log" Then
```

Can be written as using [FSO.GetExtensionName](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/filesystemobject_getextname.html):

```
If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "log" Then
```

Comment: What would the syntax be to add in for a timestamp? as in hours minutes seconds? Not going to be using this for this script but curious to know

Comment: Look at the code carefully, you will find that it is trivial :) Hint: `Right("00" & Hour(d), 2)` etc.

Comment: Ah yes. Very easy to figure out once I just looked at how date was formatted. Thank you again!